# Required Java libraries in Eclipse when working on multiple OSs

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm developing an AppEngine project in Java.
I'm working on a MacBook and on other two PCs.
I'm using a hosted SVN as my RC.

I included some libraries from the GAE plugin in my project:

```
gwt-dev.jar, gwt-user.jar', validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar.
```

I did that in the Java Build Path in the project properties. 
Every time I switch a computer, I get an error:

Project '' is missing required library: ''. Off course, the path is changing between computers.

How can I resolve this issue?
Should I remove this settings from being stored on the SVN repository? If I shpould, how can I do that?

Comment: Individual settings should be local. But the libraries shouldn't be under SCCS anyway, use Maven or similar dependency management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a project for the libraries.

Put the libraries in the project.

Export the jar files.

Set this newly created project as a dependency in the main project.

[image: build path]

[image]

Comment: my mistake was that I added an "External Jars" instead of just "Jars". thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not persist any user-specific path information.  Set your projects up by hand and then check out the user-agnostic stuff.

We have the same problem with IntelliJ.  The answer is to check in only user-agnostic information, or get an IDE that's smart enough to use relative paths.

If you add 3rd party libraries to the project, make sure they are copied into your /lib directory and not in a path that's unique to you.